# Python Initialize Function Variables

Tags: python, initialization

So I have ~200 event handlers and ~90% of them always use 3 variables (a, b, c). At the beginning of each event handler, I always initialize these variables as:

```
a = b = c = None
```

before trying to get them from the event as:

```
a, b, c = event.GetData()
```

So that if I end up in the except block, these variables exist and can be used, if available.

Is there a way to always have these variables initialized to None, without explicitly writing it at the beginning of each event handler? These event handler methods are all part of an application event handler class, if that makes any difference.

I feel like this is a silly question, but I'm trying to clean up these event handlers and want to explore all possibilities before making changes.

Comment: You can set them in the constructor of the class. You will need to show a bit more code for me to advice better

Comment: Having ~200 event handlers, almost all using the same 3 variables seems like an application in desperate need of refactoring.

Comment: @Gerrat That's what I'm working on :p. The application is pretty nicely laid out actually. These three variables serve as a sort of context ID so that event handlers can be accessed by multiple users concurrently. The event handlers are a bunch of procedures to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no way to automatically initialize them.

Possibly you'd find this cleaner?

```
try:
    result = event.GetData()
except Exception as e:
    result = (None, None, None)
a, b, c = result
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the events in a small helper class:

```
class EventData(object):
    def __init__(self, event):
        try:
            result = event.GetData()
            self.exception = None
        except Exception as e:
            result = (None, None, None)
            self.exception = e
        self.a, self.b, self.c = result
```

Then event handlers could use it to get normalized access to the event data:

```
 def handler(event):
     data = EventData(event)
     if data.exception:
        print "uh oh, there was an error:", data.exception
        return
     print "event data:", data.a, data.b, data.c
```

Comment: The idea of normalizing the event data could be taken care of with a decorator such as "@CheckEventIsValid", which I think would be cleaner than a helper function/class used inside the event handler. Also, I think the initialization of the variables *could* be done using the "with" statement, such as "with None as a", but I'd have to define a class like SuperNone, that defines the \_\_enter__ and \_\_exit__ methods. It just seems like overkill. I'll probably go with a decorator that checks the event data is valid. Thanks though.